# Error in reading XML file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am working on a project in which I'm in need to get the data stored in XML file using javascript or jQuery. My Script code is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", //I also tried POST method
                    url: "match.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(data){
                        $(data).find("mchdata match").each(function(){ //match is a tag
                            $(".container").append('<div class="head">'+ $(this).attr("src") +'</div>'); //src is an attribute of match tag.
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $(".container").text("Error occured");
                    }   
                    });
               });

        </script>
```

Html code is

```
<body>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </body>
```

Every time I run this code it's showing 'Error occurred' message in container div. I tried to inspect the page, it shows an error message like

> Failed to load file:///C:/Users/vinay%20Dahiya/Desktop/match.xml:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I don't know what does it mean. Is this the right script url 'm using

> `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

I'm trying to solve this for last 2-3 days but don't know what actually wrong in the code

XML file is [View XML file](http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do Ajax with `file://` URLs. Install an HTTP server.

Comment: Will it work on localhost?

Comment: I'm using it on Tomcat server, but still, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting a quick fix for this, since you are testing this on a local machine and nowhere near production,
go to the folder where the xml is and start a simple python server there.
use

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then you can access your file using,

```
http://localhost:8000/xxyy.xml
```

Comment: I have no idea about python. If you say I can run it in JSP !!

Comment: Do you have python installed ? or nodeJS ?

Comment: You can use any http server. You’ll find a big list here: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

Comment: @jcaron Basically,  I'm working on a sports website in JSP. I'm using Tomcat server. The XML file contains the currently ongoing cricket matches data. And I'm supposed to do this as soon as possible. I'm trying this since 2, 3 days but not getting the output. Also, I have no prior knowledge of HTTP servers you suggested.
Is there anything wrong with the code I'm using?

Comment: I saw various tutorials on youtube and tried to implement the same thing. But it's not working at all. Help me guys, It's very urgent.

Comment: The issue is that your are opening the file locally on your computer. Put the html and xml on your server, and open them there, it will solve the issue in your question.

Comment: You must understand that this AJAX request is generated in the CLIENT side and sent over to the SERVER to fetch a file IN the server NOT on the client's computer

Comment: It's working....................................Yes.....!!!!!!!!!!Thnx both of you. Can you tell me do I need to save the XML file locally? I mean, the XML file I need is saved on a URL. can I parse that file with this code.
I tried but it's giving error message again.